# Faster way to use latex with vi

Tags: latex, vi

I use VI to write my homework in latex, but I was wondering if there is a way to "store" commands in VI. I mean, instead of write every time I need:

```latex
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

can I use a command or something like this to do it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you will love the plugin [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). You type `eq<TAB>x^2-x-1=0` and it displays

```
\begin{equation}
  x^2-x-1=0
\end{equation}
```

He comes with a lot of snippets for multiple languages including Latex. Obviously you can add your own snippets.

Comment: Hi Eric, seems like is exactly what I need... but I have to actually write <TAB> or I have to press TAB?.. thanks

Comment: Press TAB to expand the snippet. As usual `:help snipmate` for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `.vimrc` or a separate file that you source into vim:

```
map! @E \begin{equation}^V^M\end{equation}^[O
```

Here `^V` means press control-V *twice*, `^M` means control-V, control-M, `^[`, means control-V, esc.

Then, when in input mode, type `@E` to expand.

Write as many abbreviations like that as you wish of course.